# Display images based of tags in wordpress blog posts

Tags: php, wordpress

What I want to do is have images display on each blogposts, the images that will be displayed will be what the post was tagged with, for example I will tag 1 post with 2 tags, design and print, I would like 2 small images to appear on that posts page.

This is the code that I have managed to scrape together, the else statement is displaying so a post will have the same amount of default-author.jpg showing as there are tags.

This makes me think that something in the foreach is not working but I'm still trying to learn and this is puzzling me, any help would be much appreciated.

```
<div class="image_wrap">
<?php
$posttags = get_the_tags(); // Get articles tags
$home = get_bloginfo('url'); // Get homepage URL

// Check if tag-slug.png exists and display it.
if ($posttags) {
foreach($posttags as $tag) {
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $image_relative_path = "/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/" . $tag->slug .".png";
    $image_path = $upload_dir['basedir'] . $image_relative_path;
    $image_url = $upload_dir['baseurl'] . $image_relative_path;

    if (file_exists($image_path)) {
    echo '<a href="' . $home . '/' . $tag->slug . '" /><img title="' . $tag->name . '" alt="' . $tag->name . '" src="' . $image_url . '" /></a>';

   // If no image found, output something else.
   } else { ?>
     <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/default-author.jpg" title="image missing"/>
   <?php }
    }
  }
 ?>
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can achieve the effect I want, images to be displayed on a blogpost [in wordpress] depending on what tag it has?

Comment: so what problem are you facing now??

Comment: at the moment it does not work correctly. it looks like it should post an image called design-design.png if it has a tag of design but its not.

Comment: the if part is not working properly i guess?

Comment: I think one of the four variables is not working correctly, and that makes the file_exists to return false and move onto the else statement. so if a post has 8 tags it will show default-author.jpg 8 times but i want it to display an image for each tag

Comment: try to print the variables and post the output

Comment: Array/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/advertising.png/home/sites/website.co.uk/public_html/wp-content/uploads/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/advertising.pnghttp://www.website.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/advertising.png

Comment: cheers for the suggestion to print vars, I think I can try a few things now.

Comment: you are welcome bro

Comment: Thanks again, got it working. I just needed to take out /wp-content/uploads/ from the $image_relative_path as that must have been coming through with the upload_dir

Comment: not a problem bro, now you can understand how you need to debug, atleast you learnt something which will help you in future, cheers mate :)